# Uso de "heme aquí"

Tags: vocabulario, gramática, verbos, etimología

Lo he visto en alguna ocasión en literatura o alguna interpretación de español antiguo, pero no es muy común, supongo que de alguna forma su uso está obsoleto. Ahora las dudas:

- ¿Cuál verbo es el usado? ¿"Haber"?
- ¿Puede conjugarse de otra forma? (¿"Hele ahí" quizás para 3ª persona?)
- ¿Se puede usar ese tipo de conjugación con otros verbos o solo aplica para este? Y si se puede, ¿cómo se llama este tipo de conjugación?
- ¿Su uso da alguna connotación extra a una oración aparte de "me encuentro aquí" o es solo para mostrar uso de español clásico?

Comment: _Para lavar el baldón,/ la mancha que nos agravia/ Conde Nuño, *henos* de Pravia._ de "La venganza de don Mendo", Pedro Muñoz Seca.

Comment: Si no estoy equivocado, se dice "helo aquí".

Comment: Creo haberlo visto _interpretado_ como "tener": heló ahí = ahí lo tienes, aprecialo tú misma...

Comment: Yo lo utilizo mucho, no me parece un termino obsoleto. Podría usarse como acá estoy o acá me tienes. A modo de simplificar los comentarios anteriores.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Segun RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=Vdqi7BIHdDXX2DkNVIMt):

> Unido a aquí, ahí y allí, o con los pronombres me, te, la, le, lo, las, los, se usa para señalar o mostrar a alguien o algo.

y segun [wikitionary](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/he#Espa.C3.B1ol):

> Unido a un pronombre personal clítico ("me, te, le, nos, os, les") o a un adverbio de lugar ("aquí, allí, ahí", etc.), señala la presencia o existencia de algo.

En ambos casos lo señalan como **adverbio**. Nunca he visto que se use como hele o algo así, aparentemente es válido (tanto como `hete`, `hela`, `helo`, etc). RAE también menciona que su origen es el árabe `ha` y no del latín `habere` por lo que parece una situación especial.

He visto discusiones al respecto (algunos ejemplos: [aquí](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=268050), [aquí](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?p=3449519#post3449519) y [aquí](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=435522)), y me pareció relevante un comentario acerca de la definicion de `he` en el Diccionario de Dudas, de Manuel Seco, 10ma. edición:

> **he.** La palabra he (en he aquí, he ahí) no es, como suelen decir las
>   gramáticas y los diccionarios, ni imperativo del verbo haber ni
>   adverbio demostrativo. Es un verbo defectivo e impersonal. Expresa la
>   mera existencia de algo en un lugar, como el impersonal hay; pero se
>   diferencia de este en que presenta siempre esa existencia «ante los
>   ojos» del oyente. Es invariable: no tiene otra forma personal,
>   temporal ni modal que esta. Lleva siempre dos acompañantes forzosos:
>   1.°, el adverbio aquí o allí (en ocasiones, otro complemento adverbial de lugar: Henos ya EN CASA); 2.°, un complemento directo: He aquí el
>   resultado; He aquí a tu madre; Heme aquí. Es palabra de uso
>   principalmente literario.

Aparte de su significado especifico, no parece tener algún otro significado extra , mas que denotar la presencia de algo o alguien específicamente frente a alguien mas (el oyente), y ciertamente da un toque de español literario/clásico.

Answer (score 2):

Clásico sí, formal también, literario por supuesto, pero no obsoleto.  No es muy común pero se sigue usando, tanto en lenguaje escrito como en oral.
Por cierto, la RAE no dice que sea un verbo sino un **adverbio**, y por tanto es invariable, no cabe conjugación, lo que varía es el pronombre al que va unido.  Mejor lo cito que lo explican muy bien:

> Adverbio. Unido a *aquí*, *ahí* y *allí*, o con los pronombres *me*, *te*, *la*, *le*, *lo*, *las*, *los*, se usa para señalar o mostrar a alguien o algo.

Answer (score -1):

Esto se refiere al verbo estar, heme aquí significa aca estoy, o aca me tienes, la verdad que es algo que ya no se usa y como tu lo dices, lo podrás encontrar en novelas o relatos  antiguos. al mismo tiempo, el verbo en cuestión es ESTAR.

Comment: Bienvenido al foro. Ayuda cuando citas fuentes.